# Excel if statement with greater than condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my excel sheet called main, I am referring to 2 cell values

```
Main C9 -   dd-mm-yyyy   
Main C10 -  (number)
```

Now on another sheet, Below conditions I am checking.

If month on Main C9 and month on main C9+1 are equal,If this is equal next condition ie, if day on Main c9 is grater than number on main C10. If this condition is true current cell value should be 0 and if it is not true, value should be 1. And In first if statement ie, Main C9 and month on main C9+1 are equal, if it false, I have to show value as 1 in current cell.

I am using below formula, but somehow it is not working.

```
=IF(TEXT(Main!$C$9,"mmm")=TEXT(Main!$C$9+1,"mmm"),IF(TEXT(DAY(Main!$C$9),"d")>Main!C$10,0,1),1)
```

Can you let me know if I am missing something here ?

Comment: can you give an example of values in C9 and C10.

Comment: C9 - 25-12-2015  C10 - 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your aprroach is ok, but don't use TEXT,

see if this works

```
=IF(MONTH(C9)=MONTH(C9+1),IF(DAY(C9)>C10,0,1),1)
```

Comment: I see that it is working on this online link, but not in my excel  : https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgQc2ivMWd0lgmZM2ZpH0FYKvHeT

Comment: It is working. I think I had a problem with cell C10. I did re-formatting and it is working now